# Error "Unable to open data source" - import .shp into GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm new to GRASS and GIS in general, so please forgive my ignorance...

I have problem with loading Vector Data (.shp) into GRASS

I used the following steps 1.1. and 1.2:
http://qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_setup.html?highlight=grass

In the end I have choice loaded layer (.shp) and when I clicked the "Run" button to begin the import, appear error: Unable to open data source

I have all files like .shx, .shp in the same directory.
I don´t know what I´m doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have .prj and .dbf as well? Can you load and view the shapefile directly into QGIS as a new vector layer?

Comment: Yes, I can. It´s strange.. I have cfg, dbf, prj, shp, shx and I can view the shapefile into QGIS. I worked with the shapefile in QGIS. I used the Topology Checker Plugin and now I want to clean the shapefile, but GRASS doesn´t work.

Comment: Which file from the exercice data are you using?

Comment: I don´t have data from some exercice, I have own data. Do you think, that the data can be wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell the reason. Can you run the same GRASS command inside the Processing toolbox?

Comment: I already know the problem. It was in way, I´m from the Czech republic and I was the data in file "škola" and GRASS can´t works with the name of file, because there is ˇ over s. In spite of it I thank you for your willingness.

Comment: You can answer your own question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. It might be helpful for others.